# "In some time" vs "at some time" vs "sometimes"

Tags: word-usage

> In some settings, in some time, typing a superscript in a `Text` style cell will auto generate an inline cell.

Is it right to use "in some time"?

Comment: It should be "sometimes"; "in some time" means "after an unspecified period of time".

Answer (score 1):

> When certain settings are enabled, typing a superscript in a Text style cell will sometimes auto-generate an inline cell.

This would correctly get your meaning across. "In some settings" means "In certain situations"; that's not what you mean here, you're literally talking about computer settings. So "When certain settings are enabled" is more appropriate. "In some time" and "at some time" are both incorrect; "sometimes" or "at times" could work, but "sometimes" is more common. Also note the change in placement of "sometimes".

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure whether this happens because of my listed settings, and I mean sometimes this happens.

Comment: @HyperGroups I see; not at all what I thought you meant. Hang on and I'll edit.